# Why cant Safari manage this dynamic cssStyle

Tags: javascript, css, safari

This seems to work OK in FF, Opera, IE (10), even chrome but safari wont have it?

```
<html> <head>

<style> .moveable_image {position:absolute; top:50px;} </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function move_image() { 
var image_top = 200
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.top = image_top;
} </script>

</head> <body> 
<input type='button' onClick='move_image()' value='move image'/> 
<img class="moveable_image" src="f/4thumb.jpg">

</body> </html>
```

it works like this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.top = "200px"
```

but not when it's calling up a 'var'?

it works calling the same var if I (could) go the name route:

```
document.images['moveable'].style.top = image_top;
```

but I need to change a whole class

here it is live: http://generationsinc.co.uk/test/safari_java_cssrule_test.html

I hope this makes sense, I've not been able to find anything covering this at all. I've even just re-installed Safari...

I realise it wont be obvious why I need to achieve this in this particular way, but that's because I've carved this annoyance out of the bowels of my project and presented it as simply as possible.

what are my options folks?

EDIT; there seems rather a lot more incompatibility on browsers only a little older... see my comments.

Is there some better way that i have missed to change a whole class of elements dynamically?

or simply a whole bunch of elements somehow?

Comment: What OS and version of Safari? Also, why are you attempting to modify the class instead of just modifying the element? What's your goal?

Comment: hello it's windows 7 and Safari 5.

Comment: hello it's windows 7pro and Safari 5.1.7, i have just tried an XPpro machine with the following results; opera 11.60 and FF21.0 work IE8, safari 5.1.4 and chrome 16.0.912.63 don't...   so it may be that there's way too much incompatibility to really pursue this? unless i'm getting something obviously wrong?

Comment: I really need to alter a whole bunch of images simultaneously as my script was getting seriously long winded, also I'm now using the element "name" for other things too. there must be a better way to do this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to set css property `top: 200px;`. See this code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head>

<style> 
.moveable_image {position:absolute; width: 100px ; top:50px;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function move_image() {
$('.moveable_image').css({"top":"200px"});
} </script>

</head> <body> 
<input type='button' onClick='move_image()' value='move image'/> 
<img class="moveable_image" src="Tupils.jpg">

</body> </html>
```

This is working for IE, Chrome and Safari.